# have flycheck override eldoc faster

Tags: flycheck, eldoc

I have both eldoc and flycheck enabled in a .el buffer.  I have a line, eg:

```
(setq load-dirs (concat emacs-repos-dir "internal"))
```

Here, load-dirs is underlined by flycheck as an error, but if point is over load-dirs then eldoc will display the definition of 'setq' for about half a second before the flycheck message is printed.  How do I reduce this timeout?

Answer (score 3):

You can change `eldoc-idle-delay` (default is 0.5) and `flycheck-display-errors-delay` (default is 0.9). Example:

```
(setq eldoc-idle-delay 0.1
      flycheck-display-errors-delay 0.2)
```

Comment: Hm...interestingly, even though flycheck-display-errors-delay is 0.9, it is showing the error immediatly.  Why would this be?